# batch file IF statement fix

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My code won't work :

```
@echo off
color 0a

:Generation
 set /a number=%random% %% 26-1

 if %number% == 1 (
 echo a
 )
 if %number% == 2 (
 echo b
)
if %number% == 3 (
echo c
)
```

It repeats that in the same format until 26 = z.
When I run the file it won't work,
how come?

Comment: As long as you are not describing what your code should do and what it actually does it is quite hard to help you...

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, but if you want `number` to be in the range  [1..26] then

```
set /a number=%random% %% 26-1
```

should be

```
set /a number=%random% %% 26+1
```

my test looks like this

```
@echo off
:Generation
set /a number=%random% %% 2

echo %number% 

if %number% == 0 (
echo a
)
if %number% == 1 (
echo b
)
```

and output looks like this

```
C:\tmp>junk.bat
0
a

C:\tmp>junk.bat
1
b

C:\tmp>junk.bat
0
a
```

Comment: I still haven't managed to get it to work, I saved it as a batch file, I've set up it like you have and it won't work.

Comment: It doesn't print out any letters above 9

Comment: can't reproduce. when echo is on, it prints for example `set /a number=29030 % 26` and then `echo 14`. what does `cmd -v` say?